# Time runs quicker before the Messiah comes; source?

Tags: talmud-gemara, messiah, time

I remember hearing that the Talmud says that before the Messiah comes, events will occur with decreasing gaps between them as if time was running faster than usual.

Where is this stated?

Comment: How do you know that such a thing is written in the Talmud? Adding that in to your question would help your answerers, and make the question more compelling.

Comment: I recall hearing this from the Ramchal, not the Talmud. Although the meaning I heard was that events will take place at a faster pace than in the past, to hurry up everything that must be done prior to the arrival of Moshiach. Not that time will actually move faster but that it will feel like it is moving faster. Things that would take years or generations in the past willtake weeks or months instead.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're referring to with time moving quicker is a misinterpretation of [Sanhedrin 98a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.98a.12):

> אמר רבי אלכסנדרי רבי יהושע בן לוי רמי כתיב (ישעיהו ס, כב) בעתה וכתיב אחישנה זכו אחישנה לא זכו בעתה
>
> Rabbi Alexandri says: Rabbi Yehoshua ben Levi raises a contradiction in a verse [addressing God’s commitment to redeem the Jewish people]. In the verse: “I the Lord in its time I will hasten it” (Isaiah 60:22), it is written: “In its time,” [indicating that there is a designated time for the redemption,] and it is written: “I will hasten it,” [indicating that there is no set time for the redemption.] Rabbi Alexandri explains: If they merit [redemption through repentance and good deeds] I will hasten [the coming of the Messiah]. If they do not merit [redemption, the coming of the Messiah will be] in its designated time. (Translation from Sefaria, explanatory phrases bracketed for clarity)

Answer (score 0):

I doubt the Talmud says that.  Maimonides writes:

> Let none suppose that in the time of the Messiah any alteration will take place in the system of the present state of the world, or any novelty in nature will be exhibited, but the world’s state will continue in its present system. [Rambam, Mishneh Torah, Kings and Wars 12:1]

Comment: Why is this relevant, the Talmud has many statements that aren't in accord with the view of Maimonides?

Comment: @Yirmeyahu -- It may not be convincing to you, but it's certainly "relevant".

Comment: How? The question isn't about whether time will slow down during the time of Moshiach.  It is about the source of of a Talmudic statement that, apparently, says something to that effect.  Maimonides view neither provides such a source nor provide us a reason to believe the Talmud doesn't make such a statement.